# PHP SOAP Request using TLS1.1

Tags: soap-api, soap

My website won't connect to salesforce.com through the SOAP API since the disablement of TLS1.0. I have made multiple changes.

I have updated OpenSSL to 1.0.2, changed the ssl.conf file in /etc/httpd/conf.d to include the line

```
SSLProtocol -all TLSv1.2
```

I have also upgraded the WSDL file.

In my code I have included the following

```
$context2 = array(
'trace' => true,
'exceptions' => true,
'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
'ssl_method' => SOAP_SSL_METHOD_TLS,  
'stream_context' => stream_context_create(array(
'ssl' => array(
            'ciphers' => 'DEFAULT:!TLSv1.0:!SSLv3:+TLSv1.1',
            'crypto_method' =>  STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLSv1_2_CLIENT
        ),
    )),
    'connection_timeout' => 15
);
```

$connection = new SforcePartnerClient();

```
//Create the SOAP connection to Salesforce
try {
$connection->createConnection($wsdl, $context2);
} catch (Exception $e) {
drupal_set_message(t('Unable to connect to Salesforce. Check 
  credentials.'), 'error');
```

The error message I 'm getting is

```
    Fatal error: SoapClient::__setSoapHeaders(): Invalid SOAP header 
in /soapclient/SforceBaseClient.php on line 326
```

This was working perfectly since last Friday. I made no changes to code for this problem to happen. I can confirm this is not a username issue because I have tried multiple users and I have reset the security token multiple times .

Comment: not really my area of expertise, however, "But this still returns a SOAP error." could you share the error? (unless i missed it)

Comment: the error message is " An AJAX HTTP error occured. HTTP Result Code path /support/download/file /ajax/870 "

Comment: this error happens on https://www.decawave.com/support/software when you click on the download button to download a piece of software.

Comment: Have you tried to change code 'ssl' => array(
            'ciphers' => 'DEFAULT:!TLSv1.0:!SSLv3:+TLSv1.1',
            'crypto_method' =>  STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLSv1_2_CLIENT
        ), to 'ssl' => array(
            'ciphers' => 'DEFAULT:!TLSv1.2:!SSLv3',
            'crypto_method' =>  STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLSv1_2_CLIENT
        ),

Comment: yes I tried that just now and with no success!